# Android Arraylist item id

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I have been a .Net developer for over 12 years and am new to Android, so the concepts are similar to me but I have been googling a lot of the specifics (and terms)...

Here's my problem -
I am querying SQLite for all the records of a specific table using a Cursor to fill an ArrayList that has been typcasted to a Object that I have created.  From there I am using an ArrayAdapter to populate a ListView.  From there on a long click, I have a listener where it has a context menu with options like Edit and Delete.  In order to do these, you need to have the original SQLite _id and I read you can get that by using AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info and then simply info.id.

In the debugger I noticed this is always set to 0.  So I went further back and found all the way back at the query when I build the ArrayList in the debugger, each item has all my field information from the query EXCEPT _id.  It does have an id field, but this is always set to 0.  I assume this is the field that I have to set in order to pass the id, but there is no method provided to do so.
Below is my SQLite Query:

```
public ArrayList<Books> getAllBooks(){
        ArrayList<Books> itemList = new ArrayList<Books>();

        String sqlQuery =
                "Select "
                + KEY_ID + ", "
                + title + ", "
                + description + ", "
                + genre + ", "
                + creation_dt + ", "
                + modification_dt
                + " From "
                + TABLE_Books;

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            //itemList.add(new Books(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2)));
            String logId = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0));
            Log.i("Book ID", "Book Title: " + cursor.getString(1) + " KEY_ID: " + logId);
            itemList.add(cursorToBook(cursor));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return itemList;
    }

    private Books cursorToBook(Cursor cursor){
        Books book = new Books();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
        book.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
        book.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
        book.setGenre(cursor.getString(3));
        return book;
    }
```

This is my Books Object:

```
public class Books {
    public int _id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String genre;
    private Date creation_dt;
    private Date modification_dt;

    public int getId(){ return _id;}
    public void setId(int Id){ this._id = _id;}

    public String getTitle(){ return title;}
    public void setTitle(String title){ this.title = title;}

    public String getDescription(){ return description;}
    public void setDescription(String description){ this.description = description;}

    public String getGenre(){ return genre;}
    public void setGenre(String genre){ this.genre = genre;}

    public Date getCreation_dt(){ return creation_dt;}
    public void setCreation_dt(Date creation_dt){ this.creation_dt = creation_dt;}

    public Date getModification_dt(){ return modification_dt;}
    public void setModification_dt(Date modification_dt){ this.modification_dt = modification_dt;}

}
```

Any and all time spent replying is greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

**Update:**
My SQLiteOpenHelper -

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //Database
    private static final String Database_Name = "novel.db";
    private static final int Database_Version = 1;

    // Table Names
    public static final String TABLE_Books = "books";
    public static final String TABLE_Chapter = "chapters";
    public static final String TABLE_major_Character = "master_character";

    //Common Columns
    public static final String column_id = "_id";

    //Book Columns
    public static final String book_title = "title";
    public static final String book_description = "description";
    public static final String book_genre = "genre";
    public static final String book_creation_dt = "creation_dt";
    public static final String book_modification_dt = "modification_dt";

    //Chapter Columns
    public static final String chapter_chapter_num = "chapter_num";
    public static final String chapter_chapter_title = "chapter_title";
    public static final String chapter_start_page = "start_page";
    public static final String chapter_end_page = "end_page";
    public static final String chapter_total_pages = "total_pages";
    public static final String chapter_synopsis = "synopsis";
    public static final String chapter_book_id = "book_id";

    //Master Character Columns
    public static final String mc_name = "name";
    public static final String mc_role = "role";
    public static final String mc_age = "age";
    public static final String mc_pertinent_info = "pertinent_info";
    public static final String mc_relevant_backstory = "relevant_backstory";

    public static final String book_create = "create table " + TABLE_Books
            + " ("
            + column_id + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + book_title + " varchar(1000), "
            + book_description + " varchar(100), "
            + book_creation_dt + " datetime, "
            + book_modification_dt + " datetime, "
            + book_genre + " varchar(250) "
            + ")";

    public static final String chapters_create = "create table " + TABLE_Chapter
            + " ("
            + column_id + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + chapter_chapter_num + " int, "
            + chapter_chapter_title + " varchar(1000), "
            + chapter_start_page + " int, "
            + chapter_end_page + " int, "
            + chapter_total_pages + " int, "
            + chapter_synopsis + " varchar(1000), "
            + chapter_book_id + " int"
            + ")";
    public static final String master_character_create = "create table " + TABLE_major_Character
            + " ("
            + column_id + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + mc_name + " varchar(1000), "
            + mc_role + " varchar(1000), "
            + mc_age + " int, "
            + mc_pertinent_info + " varchar(1000), "
            + mc_relevant_backstory + " varchar(1000) "
            + ")";

public SQLiteHelper(Context context){
    super (context, Database_Name, null, Database_Version );
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){
        database.execSQL(book_create);
        database.execSQL(chapters_create);
        database.execSQL(master_character_create);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(SQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", THIS WILL DESTROY ALL OLD DATA!");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_Books);
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_Chapter);
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_major_Character);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
My insert method

```
public void createBook(Books book){
        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
        String newDate = s.format(new Date());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(title, book.getTitle());
        values.put(description, book.getDescription());
        values.put(genre, book.getGenre());
        values.put(creation_dt, newDate);

        long book_id = db.insert(TABLE_Books, null, values);
    }
```

Comment: could you post your CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem.  I have updated the post with my SQLiteOpenHelper extension.

Comment: the autoincrement is ok. What about the inserts statement when you are adding info to that tables?

Comment: I updated with my insert command.  When I noticed the problem, in my Select Query you can see where I log.d the book title and id.  There is actually has a value (for instance 2).  Also, when debugging the cursor at item 0 has a value. I obviously don't understand ArrayLists but the id exists until I perform the itemList.add in the query.  Looking at it in the debugger, each item is populated but the id = 0 on each.

Comment: I thought your problem was on the database and you where getting 0 as _id from there.

Comment: Sorry to mislead.  My problem is that in the ArrayList the id field for a item is always set to 0.  In my query you can see where I use setId and it still remains 0 although all my other fields in item are populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html) instead of ArrayAdapter, you save a lot of code.

Something like:

```
String sqlQuery =
            "Select "
            + KEY_ID + ", "
            + title + ", "
            + description + ", "
            + genre + ", "
            + creation_dt + ", "
            + modification_dt
            + " From "
            + TABLE_Books;

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);

    String[] from = {KEY_ID, title}; // _id mandatory
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

    CursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
       context,
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
       cursor,
       from,
       to,
       CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    ListView listView = ....
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Well it has been a long day...  Getting data from a database should not be this hard.  Android has a long way to go... So what I did was use the SQLiteCursorLoader (Custom Library).  I seriously complicated things when I used more than one field in the listview.  This being said, you set me on the right path and I greatly appreciate it.  However, I don't think you can simply add a cursor to a CursorAdapter like in your example... But I'm a newbie and might be wrong..  I deeply appreciate it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**The error is in setId.** You do `This._id = _id` it should be `This._id = Id`

Also, keys values are `long` not `int`.
And is best practice avoid `0` on cursor.getLong(0).

Change

```
book.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
```

to

```
cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ID));
```

Then change `getId` and `setId` method signature to long.

After all changes, class Books will be like this:

```
public class Books {

    public long _id;

    ........

    public long getId(){ return _id;}
    public void setId(long Id){ this._id = Id;}

    ........
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I decided to abandon the object approach as listed in the accepted answer.  I was thinking like .Net (which included getting data from a data as being easy)... I want to thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Yes, the cursorAdapter is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

After `itemList.add(cursorToBook(cursor));` add this snippet,

```
Book testBook = itemList.get(itemList.size()-1);
Log.i("ID of recently inserted book is " + testBook.getId());
```

Check if this still prints value "0".

The id of AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo is rowid of the item(i.e. Book object) in the ListAdapter object (in your case,  ArrayAdapter). If the above Log.i prints correct id, then instead of using ArrayAdapter, either create new subclass  of BaseAdapter (and override getItemId method correctly) or just use CursorAdapter.